# phpmyadmin is no longer letting me set auto_increment value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I used to be able to set the auto_increment value in phpmyadmin->table->operations, but I no longer see it in this box:

http://puu.sh/4dhf4.png

It used to be right under there, yes my table has an auto_increment field. I'm using phpmyadmin 4.4.0, and I already tried switching from InnoDB to MyISAM. I'm logged into phpmyadmin with root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure why they removed this feature, but the way to do this "old school" is to click on the SQL tab and then run the following MySQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE `sessions` auto_increment = 12345
```

This would set the auto increment counter to 12345 (or to one more than the highest value already in the 'sessions' table).

Comment: I have the problem where trying to change the auto_increment value through the phpmyadmin's operations menu does not work. However it does work by applying that query in the SQL menu.

Comment: 2018 update: For those who are searching in phpmyAdmin (as I was when I came across this question) it is now in under 'Structure' tab as a checkbox in 'A_I' column.

Comment: The question is about how to "set the auto_increment value" not about how to make a field automatically increment.

Answer (score 6):

I table doens't have an auto_increment option, its the table columns that you can asign the auto_increment option to. The option is called a_i

Comment: the field does have auto_increment, yet I still don't see the option to change the value:http://puu.sh/4dhPO.png

Comment: click on the database, click on the table, click on structure, select the field checkbox of ur id, select change. Check the box of A_I. Click save

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. I've just tested a few recent versions and don't have that trouble. The only time I can get it to not display that field is if there's no auto_increment set. Can you post a screenshot or SQL dump of your database structure so I can try to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using phpMyAdmin, you can click your table name and then click on the "structure" tab. underneath extras is where you would put auto-incriment.  If that doesnt work, make sure the user you are logging into your table with has permissions to make such a change. The Query to make a field auto-increment would be something like.

> CREATE TABLE Employee(
>   ID int NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   Name varchar(255)
>   );

In this case, the field ID would auto-incriment